# How to define kubernetes configmap for multiple routes in Spring Cloud Gateway[Kubernetes]

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway

How should the **kubernetes ConfigMap yaml** definition be for more than one route in Spring Cloud Gateway?

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=spring-gateway
server.port=8080

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://example1:8082/
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].name=Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].args[0]=/user/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=TestFilter1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=TestFilter2

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://example2:8083/
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0].name=Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0].args[0]=/account/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=TestFilter1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[1]=TestFilter2
```